# How to configure implementation 'com.mindorks.android:placeholderview:1.0.3' in android studio Java

Tags: java, xml, build.gradle

Its saying "Failed to resolve: com.mindorks.android:placeholderview:1.0.3
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app"

```
<com.mindorks.placeholderview.SwipePlaceHolderView 
    android:id="@+id/swipeView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingClass" 
/>
```

this is what am trying to use for swipe sliders
Your help will be highly appreciated please

1. This is the error its showing have been trying for weeks now nothing have tried on google it     seem not to work have
2. Have tried to use the lower version nothing have tried to the following
   a. To rebuild the project
   b. To restart the project
   c. To clean the project

Nothing is working
this is the xml fail which is not showing saying missing class

1. I was expecting the xml class to be imported so i can finish the app but that error has done me bad

```
<com.mindorks.placeholderview.SwipePlaceHolderView 
    android:id="@+id/swipeView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingClass" 
/>
```

your help will be appreciated thanks in advance for your help.